# How to trigger the enter keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know how to trigger an enter key on an input.  That is, in response to some other event (not a keypress), I need to trigger a keypress of value 13.

(Clarification, I do not want to trigger some event when the enter key is pressed. If I didn't know how to do that, I could find that that's been asked and answered several times on SO. I want the reverse. I am trying to develop a workaround that requires I emulate an 'enter' keypress.)

Comment: what about this one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276794/jquery-or-pure-js-simulate-enter-key-pressed-for-testing

Comment: Has a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/3xTM2/

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can do this -

```
var e = $.Event( "keypress", { which: 13 } );
$('#yourInput').trigger(e);
```

- http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/
- http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Note however this will simply trigger the event, default behaviors won't actually occur. http://jsfiddle.net/YkLhs/

Comment: @KevinB, is there some method by which we can trigger the default behaviors? The evidence is indisputable that this works, yet it's not triggering the behavior I need.

Comment: Try looking at it from another direction. Why do you need to simulate this event?

Comment: @KevinB, yesterday I asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197223/is-it-possible-to-paste-a-list-to-a-select2-field-and-test-each-item-in-the-list. As you can see, no answers. But I have noticed that in select2, if you enter a search term that matches and press enter, the item is added to the list of matched objects.  Thus, I am setting up a 'paste' event and splitting the pasted list by commas and spaces. I was hoping that if I triggered enter after each token, it would behave as if I had typed in the term and pressed enter, but alas that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: From the documentation, all that takes is `$("#selectid").select2("val", ["thefirstvalue","thesecondvalue","thethirdvalue"]);`

Comment: @KevinB, I really wish that were all it takes. :(  But alas, that does not work.

Answer (score 4):

```
 var e = $.Event( "keyup", { keyCode: 13 } );
    $('#yourInput').trigger(e);
```

Worked for me, instead of 'which', I used 'keyCode'

Answer (score 2):

**Simulate enter keypress**

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
        e.which = 13 
        e.keyCode = 13
        $('#email').focus();
        $('#email').trigger(e);
```

**capture enter keypress**

```
$('#email').keypress(function (e) {
if (e.which == '13') {
    alert('code');
}});
```