# Clear an alert message

Tags: javascript, react-native

Let's say I have a code like this:

```
alert('Hello World')
```

So on my device is going to appear an alert message saying 'Hello World'. That message will be there until I press Ok.

But is there  any way to remove the alert message from the screen with code? Instead of pressing Ok on the device?

Comment: You could simulate the ENTER keypress. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217892/how-to-trigger-the-enter-keypress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

> [Javascript close alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463368/javascript-close-alert-box)

Not even in `react-native`. Best alternative would be to use custom dialogs or modals.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:
https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr