# Trigger Enter keypress in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to trigger an enter keypress event on my input without actually pressing the enter key, more just onload.

I found out that [initKeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyboardEvent) and [initKeyEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyEvent) are both deprecated even e.[keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) and e.[which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) are being removed from web standards.

[I also found this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17217918/710887) that goes over how to do this in jQuery. However, I've been trying to figure out how to do this in vanilla JS and no luck.

```js
var txtbox = document.getElementById('txtbox');
txtbox.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert('enter key pressed');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
};

var ev = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
// Send key '13' (= enter)
ev.initKeyboardEvent(
    'keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 13, 0);
document.body.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtbox" placeholder="trigger enter key press">
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since initKeyboardEvent is deprecated use constructor instead: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

event.key is not deprecated so we can use key === "Enter"

Also trigger enter on txtbox instead of body

```
var txtbox = document.getElementById('txtbox');
txtbox.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.key == "Enter") {
    alert('enter key pressed');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
};

var ev = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {altKey:false,
  bubbles: true,
  cancelBubble: false, 
  cancelable: true,
  charCode: 0,
  code: "Enter",
  composed: true,
  ctrlKey: false,
  currentTarget: null,
  defaultPrevented: true,
  detail: 0,
  eventPhase: 0,
  isComposing: false,
  isTrusted: true,
  key: "Enter",
  keyCode: 13,
  location: 0,
  metaKey: false,
  repeat: false,
  returnValue: false,
  shiftKey: false,
  type: "keydown",
  which: 13});

txtbox.dispatchEvent(ev);
```