# How To click ENTER button Using Javascript in web console?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, console

This Website Has one text boxes, There Is no button on that webpage it needs to click the enter button on the keyboard to work.

I successfully entered text into text area :

```
document.getElementById("lookup-user-username").value="Name  Here";
```

I need To Press Enter Button Using the chrome Web Console At This movement. Can Anyone Help?

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrR5K.png)

Website:
[website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcjwt.png)

Comment: "trigger enter key javascript"

Comment: do you really doing web-scraping using chrome developer tool? Other library may have native solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I execute a function on pressing the enter key in an <input> field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011312/how-can-i-execute-a-function-on-pressing-the-enter-key-in-an-input-field)

Comment: no i need to click enter button using command like "document.getElementById("btn").click();"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775289/trigger-enter-keypress-in-vanilla-js

Comment: @epascarello using onkeydown and searching for the keyCode is definitely a better approach, but it doesn't make my recommendation invalid.

Comment: @AGE THE OP is not listening for an event. They are trying to fire it. The OP even said it was wrong. The OP is automating the page, not coding it.

Comment: noted, I went with the assumption that adding an event listener would be helpful to their use case which is what my recommended link suggests as an approach (on key down)

Comment: I am doing web-scraping ('https://www.twitchfollowing.com/') I need to *click Enter Button On Keyboard* By using the web console. I really don't know it is possible or not.