# Can't get paste working with select2 4.0 to insert multiple items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Paste was working in previous versions of select2, taking `tokenSeparator` in account to split pasted term into multiple tags.

Now, I just can't get it running anymore.

Here's how I'm calling select2:

```
$('select').select2({
  tags: true,
  multiple: true,
  tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
  width: 200
 });
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXoXqO . Try to paste: `Gods,Angels,Devils`

I also tried to use the `tokenizer` method, as described here: [Auto tokenize last item in pasted string using select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367499/auto-tokenize-last-item-in-pasted-string-using-select2), but got this error:
`select2.js:3503 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'term' of undefined`

Comment: [This is a known issue in Select2 4.0.0](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3458).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue at select2 4.0.0, reported here: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3458

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried to write my own tokenizer but it seems that somehow `select2 4.0.x` also calls it's own tokenizer (and that's why you got that error, @Eric Saboia).

I could not fix it properly, so I would suggest either waiting for a bug fix, using a similar working lib like http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/ or writing your own component (maybe with React).