# Is it possible to change the input in a select field?

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a form with two select fields for which I use select2 to match & tokenize what ever is inserted into the field. I need to convert a list of inputs separated by a new line to a list separated by a space (because IE doesn't do this automatically).

I have the following code which works fine with any `<input>` fields:

```
$('#editor').bind('paste', function (e) {
            var clipped = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
            clipped = clipped.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " "); //replace newlines with spaces
            $(this).val(clipped);
            alert(clipped);
            return false; //cancel the pasting event
        });
```

but it does not seem to work if #editor is a `<select>` field.

```
<form method="POST" action="/run" class="ui-widget" onsubmit=" return confirmSubmit(this, 'run',true) ">
    Editor:
    <select name="editor" id="editor" multiple style="width: 200px">
        <option>ALL</option>
    </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

any idea what is missing?

Comment: As far as I can see IE does not even support pasting into select fields.

Comment: it works if i have the `multiple style` and matcher in the select2 option.

Comment: I don't get any "paste" events with select2. Compare here: http://jsfiddle.net/ct5172sk/

Comment: Yes, it does not seem to recognise them. That's the problem.

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what your trying to do, you may want to rephrase your q and/or provide a complete code demo.  But I think this may be what your looking for:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17238679/1922144

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe paste is possible on select

A work-around could be:

- create an invisible input
- bind keydown event on select field
- check if the key is control key
- if so, change focus to invisible input
- catch value there once the paste event is done on this input
- change value of select item to the value of the input :)

edit:

- change focus back to select field