# Create/Add multiple options(tags) in select2 by parsing the provided (copy+pasted) string in select2 input box

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

**Problem Statement**

I have a use case in which I need to parse and convert string into multiple tags and add them as select2 selected tags. I am aware of the tokenSeperator, but can't use it as it's not fulfilling my use case to parse the string.

So, is there any way that I can provide custom tokenizer in select2, which will get called before invoking createTag or insertTag methods. Also, some way to mark these multiple tags as selected.

**Use Case example**

1. User copy+paste following string in select2 input box,
   one, two, three, $four+, 78$, five, $six, seven$
2. My custom parser seperate this string as,
   a. "one"
   b. "two"
   c. "three"
   d. "four+, 78"
   e. "five"
   f. "six, seven"
3. I want to convert these strings tags and mark them as selected as soon as user copy+paste provided string in select2 input box and hits enter.

**Resources**

[Select2 Documentation](https://select2.org/)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Please also read how to create a [mcve].

Comment: https://select2.org/configuration/options-api states you can use `tokenizer:` callback option.   Documentation is missing for it, but shouldn't be too hard to work it out / review the source or find an existing question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17238679/2181514